# change y axis in species accumulation curves in vegan into percentages

Tags: r, vegan

I would like to create a species accumulation curve in R (I tried using the vegan package), but instead of showing the number of species on the y axis, I would like to indicate the % of total number of species on the y axis. This would allow me to calculate e.g. with how many sites sampled, I can find 50% of total species present.

Thanks for any help!
Ellen

example dataset to play with

```
require(vegan)
data(dune)
plot(specaccum(dune,method="random"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the `specaccum` output

```
accum <- specaccum(dune,method="random")
accum$sd <- accum$sd/max(accum$richness)*100
accum$richness <- accum$richness/max(accum$richness)*100
plot(accum)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not receive a notification of your answer, hence the late answer ;)

Comment: If it was useful to you, considering accepting the answer